# Not able to invoke werservice from client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am new to webservices and have developed a very  basic webservice for the class as below :

```
@WebService
public class Hello {
  public String helloName(String Name){
    return "hello there " + Name;
  }
}
```

The webservice is deployed and I can access the wsdl file on browser. But when I invoke the service through a client, it gives an error as `java.net.UnknownHostException`

I observed in the wsdl file is that the soap:address tag still shows address location localhost:8080 even after the service is deployed on the server. Not very sure if this can be a source of error.

```
<wsdl:service name="HelloService">
  <wsdl:port name="HelloPort" binding="tns:HelloServiceSoapBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HAYServer/Hello"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving the endpoint url with "?wsdl" while invoking service, then remove that and try.

If thats not the issue then give more details like : 
1) Full error stacktrace
2) The API with which you have implemented webservice (CXF, Axis etc).
3) The webservice client code with which your are trying to invoke the service.